# If Operator Taking Three Parameters

Tags: vb.net, syntax

So, I am working on a project, and have encountered some strange syntax I have not seen, previously. Again, this is in VB.Net and **the code works**. This is **not** a debug question. So, what's going on in this VB.Net code fragment (clarification of question below code):

```
Dim dt As String = If(OtherObject.Length > 1, OtherObject(1), "")
```

Here's what's troubling me, this is **not** a `IIF` statement, but it appears to be functioning as one (?).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Thanks. I have actually been following that thread (but had forgotten about it until you reminded me). Good call. I kept the change, but I do disagree with the prevailing consensus

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're seeing the [If Operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513985.aspx):

> Uses short-circuit evaluation to conditionally return one of two values. The If operator can be called with three arguments or with two arguments.

especially the the If Operator called with three arguments:

> When If is called by using three arguments, the first argument must evaluate to a value that can be cast as a Boolean. That Boolean value will determine which of the other two arguments is evaluated and returned. The following list applies only when the If operator is called by using three arguments.

---

> Here's what's troubling me, this is not a IIF statement, but it appears to be functioning as one (?).

It replaced the now obsolete [IIf method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.interaction.iif.aspx). The advantage over `IIf` is that `If`, beeing an operator instead of a method, supports short-circuit evaluation. `IIf` will always evaluate both arguments.

Answer (score 0):

When used this way IF is a short circuiting ternary operator.  Using IIF evaluates both sides.

http://www.panopticoncentral.net/2007/05/08/iif-becomes-if-and-a-true-ternary-operator/

Basically there is an If..Then...Else **statement**, most people call the If Statement, in VB.NET, and there is an If **operator**, that you stumbled on.

Answer (score 0):

This IF operator is declaring the string "dt" and giving it a value in the same line of code. The first argument of the If statement is the logical question and the second and third arguments are what the statement will return if true and if false respectively.

If the length of otherobject is greater than 1 then dt will be the item in otherobject with index 1 {otherobject(1)}.

If the length of otherobject is not greater than 1, the statement is false and dt will be "" or blank.